# can't remove laravel_database_ prefix from channel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

I'm setting up Laravel echo to broadcast events. But whenever I try to broadcast to a channel the channel name gets an automatic prefix: 'laravel_database_'

I've tried switching the return inside the Event to a regular 'Chanel' as following:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
return new Channel('public');
}
```

but when I look into the laravel-echo-server logs I see it is still being broadcasted on: 'laravel_database_public'.

This way I would need to do the following in my JS:

```
Echo.channel('laravel_database_public').listen('MessageSent', ({message}) => {
                console.log(message);
            });
```

But ofcourse, I want to remove the prefix (or figure out why its there). Hopefully someone can clear this up for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is configurable in `config/database.php` (and I believe even removable) under

```php
'redis' => [
    'options' => [
        'prefix' => // change here.
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

<del>The accepted answer does not work with [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server).</del>

The solution is rather to let the whole Redis Laravel config *untouched* and to run version `^1.6.0` of laravel-echo-server with the proper `keyPrefix` option in `laravel-echo-server.json` config file:

```
{
   "databaseConfig": {
     "redis": {
       "keyPrefix": "laravel_database_"
      }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28701#issuecomment-557155843)

Comment: Thanks for this additional answer. I am currently making a new project and will update the answer if what you say is true.

Comment: It *is* actually working if you set `REDIS_PREFIX=""`. Regardless, namespacing the Laravel events in the Redis database is certainly a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

As at Laravel 7, the `config/database.php` looks like this

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_'),
        ],
    ]
```

So it searches the `.env` file for your `REDIS_PREFIX` variable, if there's none, then it generates `laravel_database_` or based on whatever you set `APP_NAME` to in your `.env` file.

All you have to do is set your `REDIS_PREFIX`. You can leave it empty so that there is no prefix at all.